# multiple queries at once and Contains condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query

```
select b.country, a.account_name from account a join market b on a.ACCOUNT_ID = b.ACCOUNT_ID
and account_type = 'xxx'
and b.is_value = 0
order by 1
```

The result would be as below (multiple countries with account names will result, giving 3 countries as an example)

```
account type            country                 account_name
-----------------------------------------------------------------
xxx                     MALTA                   Current
yyy                     UKRAINE                 Current
zzz                     UNITED KINGDOM          Current
```

**If in the result**, if MALTA and UNITED KINGDOM **exists**, then I need to copy the account_name and paste it in an excel sheet against the account type and "YES" as a 3rd column of the excel

**If in the result**, if MALTA and UNITED KINGDOM **doesnt exists**, then I need to enter "NO" in the 3rd column of the excel

**I have more than 3000 account types to deal with**, and this is such a time taking task for me.

Is there a way where I can write a query for all the 3000 account types in a single shot so that I can have below out put (**whenever country is in MALTA and UNITED KINGDOM its YES, else NO**)

```
account_type            account_name                Status
-----------------------------------------------------------------
xxx                     Current                     YES
yyy                     Current                     YES
zzz                     Current                     NO
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your existing query and use a `CASE` statement to get the 3rd column like below

```
select a.account_type,
a.account_name,
case when b.country = 'MALTA' or b.country = 'UNITED KINGDOM' then 'YES'
else 'NO' end as Status  
from account a join market b 
on a.ACCOUNT_ID = b.ACCOUNT_ID    
and b.is_value = 0
order by 1
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for the response. This displays me the whole list of countries and I can run the query again for a single account type only. as part of Else "NO" condition, nothing will be displayed as a result set.

Comment: sorry if my question was misleading, I am trying to run the whole list of more than 3000 account types at once, so that I will get a result of (account type, account name and YES/NO)

Comment: Can you post your desired output. Edit your post and include that as well.

Comment: @Techie, That's pretty easy. Check edited query again.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for the update. as explained in the question, for every account type, i will have multiple countries with account names. I dont want to have all those rows(for each account type i will have more than 40 rows), I just want to a single row for account type with accessory name and Status

Comment: I tried to include (where b.country = 'MALTA' or b.country = 'UNITED KINGDOM' ) which gives me two rows with Malta and UK. Do I need to include all the countries in question in the where condition ? (because whenever I dont specify other countries in the where condition and for any account type if there are no results for Malta and UK, i will get no rows at all)